# Can you say "unconfident", as in the opposite of being/having confidence?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, is-it-a-word

Can you say *unconfident*? I heard it mentioned in Top Chef recently, where a chef mentioned she was unconfident with her cooking skills in a certain area.

Is this the correct way to describe the opposite of having confidence?

Is *inconfidence* a word? I have heard it mentioned as "lack of confidence".

I am not a native English speaker.

**Update:** I did look it up on [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconfident) before posting but should of course have included my findings here. But I just noticed that I might have not just read the add. I thought m-w didn't have the word listed, but really the add says something different.

Oxford has it listed as someone mentions though.

To clarify, I'm asking if *unconfident* is the correct word to use for describing the opposite of being confident, mainly because "it sounded a bit odd to me", I thought inconfident might be more correct, but as someone mentions, that isn't a word. I personally preferred "I lack confidence in my skills" but I doubt you would hear that a lot in spoken language.

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Comment: And hence why the upvote for lack of research?

Comment: This is three questions in one. Of which one and a half you immediately answer yourself. ("Can you say *unconfident*? I heard it". Well.) Also, as the top comment points out, dictionaries are a thing and should be the starting point for any "is it a word" question. If you still have questions left after that, you are welcome to edit your post to include the additional information. Right now it's all over the map. Please clarify what it is you are actually after.

Comment: There are no issues with *unconfident*. And *inconfident* = *unconfident*. Relax & enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "Doubtful" is the right word. I don't think unconfident is the correct word.

You can even use "Unsure" as the opposite of Confident.

The [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unconfident) says:

> **unconfident**
>
> *adjective*
>
> not confident; hesitant:
>
> the airmen were young, but not unconfident
>
> very young people may have an unconfident approach

And it would be correct if the Top chef would have said that she was not confident with her cooking skills in a certain area.

> Is inconfidence a word?

No there is no such word.

Comment: It depends what you mean by _word_. The OED has an entry for ‘inconfidence’ with two supporting citations, one from 1627 and one from 1811. The definition is given as ‘want of confidence, distrust’, but it is described as 'rare'.

Comment: No, _doubtful_ doesn't fit at all. It is more often used for the information or situation about which there is doubt than for the person who is doing doubting; and it refers to a doubt about some specific outcome or answer, rather than a general sense of doubt. _Unsure_ might do, but still would not necessarily be opposed to _confident_.

Comment: And I think you mean "if the Top chef **had** said that she was not **confident** with ... ".

Comment: @ColinFine:- Yes I meant confident.

Comment: @ColinFine possibly, in Indian English (I'm guessing from the poster's name,) doubtful, does carry the meaning of being unsure of one's abilities. If you doubt whether your expertise is up to standard, then you lack confidence.

Answer (score -1):

I would use 'lacking in confidence'.

'In some of my recipes I am lacking in confidence'

Comment: _In_ some of your recipes?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, 'in' is correct isn't it? I could have said 'I lack confidence in some of my recipes'. Or does the use of the present continuous necessitate a change to 'with'. 'I am lacking in confidence with some of my recipes'?

Comment: ?In the Government I have confidence? Perhaps in an oratorical register. I think 'have confidence in' normally behaves as a non-separable MWV.